# How can I predict in a good way an increasing trend of the amplitude of a pattern looking like sinus wave with some noise on it

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to  predict with scikit learn traffic which is pretty close to a sinus
However the amplitude is continuously increasing and decreasing slightly.

[image]

the models I used and found seem to ignore this increasing amplitude.
To see what i mean ? just run the below code and you will see it in the plots.(maybe you get an indentation error, then select all the code and shift-tab of course)
The first plot shows the input traffic, and the second plot shows the original traffic including the predicted values on top of the original values. You can play with the parameters and verify that the models ignore the increase of the amplitude.
The code runs in Jupyter, but also in Spyder for sure. No real trick in there (you can ignore the warnings)

Question : Does anyone actually tested a model with predicting traffic with a
changing amplitude successfully and what was the model and which hyperparameters did you use.
or perhaps you used a neural network for it.... Would really appreciate your help

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # coding: utf-8
    
    # In[2]:
    
    
    print("load modules")
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
    import pyodbc
    import os
    import glob
    import sys
    import shutil
    from os import listdir
    from shutil import copyfile
    from os.path import isfile, join
    import pysftp
    import time
    import datetime
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
    import seaborn as sns
    import random
    #import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
    #from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score,cross_validate
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error, mean_absolute_error
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn import svm
    #from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
    #from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    #from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
    from sklearn import linear_model
    #from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    #from joblib import dump, load
    #import pickle
    #from openpyxl import load_workbook
    #from csv import reader
    print("modules loaded")
    
    def traffic(dftraffic):
        j=0
        length= len(dftraffic)
        dftraffic["Sinus"] = float(0)
        noiselevel = 0
        peakheight = 2
        peak = False
        weeklevel = 4
    
        while j<length:
            
            slope = 1 + 0.1 * ( 1 + dftraffic["Day"][j] - dftraffic["Day"].min())/         ( 1 + dftraffic["Day"].max() - dftraffic["Day"].min())
            
            # generate a peak during 1 random hour during the week
            if peak and dftraffic["Weekday"][j] == random.randint(1,7) and dftraffic["Hour"][j] == random.randint(0,23) :
                dftraffic["Sinus"][j] = peakheight * random.randint(0,9)          
            
            # anticipate from  weekend to week
            elif dftraffic["Weekday"][j] == 7 and dftraffic["Hour"][j] >= 22:
                dftraffic["Sinus"][j] = slope * weeklevel * (np.sin(2 * np.pi / 24 * dftraffic["Hour"][j]) + 1) +             random.randint(0,9)*noiselevel
    
            #Lower traffic during weekends with noise on the level + base level to avoid negative values
            elif dftraffic["Weekday"][j] >= 6:
                dftraffic["Sinus"][j] = slope * (np.sin(2 * np.pi / 24 * dftraffic["Hour"][j]) + 1) +             random.randint(0,9)*noiselevel
    
            # anticipate from week to weekend
            elif dftraffic["Weekday"][j] == 5 and dftraffic["Hour"][j] >= 20:
                dftraffic["Sinus"][j] = slope * (np.sin(2 * np.pi / 24 * dftraffic["Hour"][j]) + 1) +             random.randint(0,9)*noiselevel
                
            # Generate weekly traffic, which 5 times higher than weekendtraffic and generate noise on it + base level to avoid negative values
            else:
                dftraffic["Sinus"][j] = slope * weeklevel * (np.sin(2 * np.pi / 24 * dftraffic["Hour"][j]) + 1) +             random.randint(0,9)*noiselevel
            j += 1
        return dftraffic
    
    def cdate(x):
        cd = int((time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime( x , "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))/3600/24 - 18870 + 44438)
        return cd
    
    def datelist():
        dates=[]
        for i in range(1,31):
            for j in range(0,24):
                dates = [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, i, j, 0, 0)
                          ] + dates
        return dates
    
    def Daylist():
        Days=[]
        for i in range(1,31):
            for j in range(0,24):
                Days = [cdate(str(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, i, j, 0, 0))[0:10])
                          ] + Days
        return Days
    
    def Weekdaylist():
        Weekday=[]
        for i in range(1,31):
            for j in range(0,24):
                Weekday = [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, i, j, 0, 0).weekday() + 1
                          ] + Weekday
        return Weekday
        
    def Hourlist():
        Hour = []
        for i in range(1,31):
            for j in range(0,24):
                Hour = [j] + Hour
        return Hour
        
    def plot_xy(x,y):
        # 2. Setup plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,16))
        plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
        fig.suptitle("Traffic pattern model", fontsize=20)
        plt.xlabel("Date", fontsize=18)
        plt.xticks(fontsize=10, rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='center')
        plt.yticks(fontsize=10, rotation='horizontal')
        plt.title("model traffic Sinus", fontsize=15)
        plt.ylabel("Sinus", fontsize=16)
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.set_facecolor('#e0eeff')
        #ax.legend("Legend",loc=0,prop=fontP)
        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20,12)    
        plt.grid(b=True, which='major',  linestyle='-') #color='#888888',
        plt.minorticks_on()
        plt.grid(b=True, which='minor',  linestyle='-', alpha=0.2) #color='#999999',
        # 3. Plot data
        ax.plot(x, y, color='blue')
    
    def save_modeltraffic(dfmodel,directory,sheetname="sheet1"):
        with pd.ExcelWriter(directory) as writer:  
                        dfmodel.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name=sheetname)
        
        
    dates10= datelist()
    d = {'DateTime': [], 'Day': [],"Weekday": [],"Hour": []}
    dfdates10 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    dfdates10["DateTime"] = datelist()
    dfdates10["Day"] = Daylist()
    dfdates10["Weekday"] = Weekdaylist()
    dfdates10["Hour"] = Hourlist()
    dfdates10 = dfdates10.sort_values(by=["DateTime"],ascending=True)
    dfdates10 = dfdates10.reset_index(drop=True)
    dfdates10["Sinus"] = float(0)
    
    dfdates10 = traffic(dfdates10)
    
    dfSin = dfdates10
    
    #dfSin = pd.read_excel(f"./sample.xlsx",usecols="A:BM")
    save_modeltraffic(dfdates10,"./modeltraffic.xlsx","modeltraffic")
    
    x = dfSin["DateTime"]
    y = dfSin["Sinus"]
    plot_xy(x,y)
    
    
    # In[234]:
    
    
    ###############################################################################################################################
    
    #             # RUN MACHINE ROUTINE, FILL MODELSCORES, PREDICTION MATRIX, PLOT PREDICTION GRPAHS AND FEATURE DEPENDANCIES
    #               NUMBER OF REPORTED DAYS X  NUMBER OF KPIS 
    
    ###############################################################################################################################
    print("Start ML routine")
    grid_Adaboost = {"n_estimators":[10,15,50,100],
                     "loss":["linear","square"],
                     "learning_rate":[0.1,0.5,1]
                    }
    
    try:
        os.remove("./Sinus_pred.png")
    except:
        print("Sinus.png not removed")
    
    #load model hyperparameters
    
    #Define numpy array for feature implementations matrix
    dfTest = dfSin[dfSin["Day"] >= (44478)]
    dfTest_exDate = dfTest.drop("DateTime", axis = 1)
    dfTest_exDate_exErl = dfTest_exDate.drop("Sinus", axis = 1)
    
    #prepare X_train, y_train
    dfXTrain = dfSin[dfSin["Day"] < (44478) ]  # exclude Testday from X_train
    #dfXTrain = dfXTrain[dfXTrain["Weekday"] == int(dfTest["Weekday"].mean())] # Only get same weekdays as testday into X_train
    dfXTrain_exDate = dfXTrain.drop("DateTime", axis = 1)
    dfXTrain_exDate_exErl = dfXTrain_exDate.drop("Sinus", axis = 1)
    
    # Use days-2 as model data and day-1 as testdata
    X_train = dfXTrain_exDate_exErl
    X_test = dfTest_exDate_exErl
    y_train = dfXTrain_exDate["Sinus"]
    y_test = dfTest_exDate["Sinus"]
    dfT1 = pd.DataFrame(dfXTrain["DateTime"])
    dfT1["Sinus"] = dfXTrain["Sinus"]
    
    #print(f"KPI {j} {rd} {bdate(itest)} #Xtrainrows={X_train.Day.count()}, {Yparam[j][p]} calculating : ", int(dfTest["Weekday"].mean()))            
    
    #Split dataset with Python
    X = dfXTrain_exDate_exErl
    y = dfXTrain_exDate["Sinus"]
    #X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    
    #model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)                 --> shows an error
    #model = RandomForestRegressor()                                             # GOOD RESULTS
    #model = LinearSVC(penalty="l2", loss="squared_hinge", dual=True)            --> gives an error
    #model = LinearRegression()                                                  --> no good results
    #model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=4,weights="distance")               --> no good results
    #model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42)                              # GOOD RESULTS
    #model = linear_model.BayesianRidge()                                        --> no good results
    #model = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=42)                          # pretty GOOD RESULTS
    #model = svm.SVR(kernel='precomputed')                                       --> not suitable
    loss = "square"
    nestimator = 300
    learningrate = 0.1
    maxdepth = 24
    
    #Optimized version of Adaboost
    #BEST MODELS
    model = AdaBoostRegressor(DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=maxdepth),
                              n_estimators=nestimator,
                              learning_rate=learningrate,
                              loss=loss,
                              random_state=42)
    #Model = AdaBoostRegressor(DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5),n_estimators=5,learning_rate=1,loss="linear",random_state=42)
    #model = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators=nestimator,loss=loss,learning_rate=learningrate,random_state=42)
    
    j = 0
    # Perform gridsearch with KPI j=10
    if j == 1: # j = number of KPI which needs to be optimized
        gs_model = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,
                      param_grid=grid_Adaboost,
                      cv=5, # 5-fold cross-validation
                      verbose=3) # print out progress      
        gs_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print(f"Sinus _ {gs_model.best_params_}")
    
    print("fit model")
    #train the model with trainingdata
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_preds = model.predict(X_test)
    dfy_preds = pd.DataFrame(y_preds)
    
    # Evaluate the models using crossvalidation
    #scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
    #scores = show_scores(model)
    #print(scores)
    #evaluate(model, X, y, cv)
    
    
    ##############  Generate plot with predicted values ###################
    
    print("prepare graph")
    #prepare x, y, z for graph
    dfT1 = dfSin
    dfT1 = dfT1[dfT1["Day"] > 44450]
    dfT1 = dfT1.drop("Day",axis = 1)
    dfT2 = dfTest[["DateTime","Sinus"]]
    dfT2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    #dfy_preds = pd.DataFrame(y_preds)
    dfy_preds["y_preds"] = y_preds
    dfy_preds = dfy_preds.drop([0],axis=1)
    dfT2["y_preds"] = dfy_preds["y_preds"]
    
    dfT3 = pd.concat([dfT1,dfT2])
    dfT3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"./ML_dfSin.xlsx") as writer: 
            dfTest.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name="X_test")
            y_test.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name="y_test")
            dfXTrain.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name="X_train")
            y_train.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name="y_train")
            dfy_preds.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name="y_preds")
            dfT3.to_excel(writer, index = True, sheet_name="dfT3")
            print(f"./data/Out/ML_dfSin.xlsx saved")
    
    x = dfT3["DateTime"] #pd.Series([x for x in range(len(dfT3.index))]) dfT3['dfxas'] #
    y = dfT3["Sinus"]
    z = dfT3["y_preds"]
    
    fontP = FontProperties()
    fontP.set_size('small')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,12))
    plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
    fig.suptitle("Trainingdata cleaned excl. SW and incidents : Sinus", fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel("Date", fontsize=18)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=10, rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='center')
    plt.yticks(fontsize=10, rotation='horizontal')
    plt.title(f"x axis up to : Sinus", fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel("Sinus", fontsize=16)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_facecolor('#e0eeff')
    ax.legend("Sinus",loc=0,prop=fontP)
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20,12)    
    plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#888888', linestyle='-')
    plt.minorticks_on()
    plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
    
    ax.plot(x, y, color='blue')
    ax.plot(x, z, color='red')  
    
    #fig.savefig("./png/Sinus_pred.png")
    plt.show()
    #plt.close()
    
    print("Sinus","   ",learningrate," ",loss,"   ",nestimator)
    print("KPI Sinus calculated : ", int(dfTest["Weekday"].mean()))
    print("Machine Learning finished")
    
    ##################       Machine Learning Loop is finished      #######################-----------------
    
    
    # In[ ]:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. providing only the minimum code to reproduce the problem and also adding the graphs as images to your example (users with more reputation can embed them for you) will greatly aid your Question!

Comment: I retried a copy paste in Jupyter notebook and for me it works... This is more or less the minimum code to reproduce the issue. Sorry this does not work on your system.... I also tried SARIMA and tensorflow2.... they all tend to have issues with picking up a trend of an increasing amplitude of waves... Would be great  if a solution could be found

Comment: Reducing your code a minimal example is _necessary research_ to show you've tried to solve your own issue before bringing it to the community and understand it thoroughly! You can still provide all of your notebook, but you could indicate, for example, in another small code block where the issue occurs. Additionally, if some generated plots or other outputs illustrate the issue or if you've tried further solutions, include them! (note you won't be able to embed images directly, but by uploading them, users with more reputation can embed them for you!)

Comment: I solved the issue thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: Excellent and anytime! You can Answer your own Question if you like to gain reputation and help the community!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ampl_increase_Sine]

```py
model = AdaBoostRegressor(
    DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=maxdepth),
    n_estimators=nestimator,
    learning_rate=learningrate,
    loss=loss,
    random_state=42
)
```

This model will pick up the increasing amplitude, but only if you include enough history, where this increasing trend has been shown before, so that the model can adapt the parameters to it. Typical parameters, which I used were presented in the previous code in the question. The red part in the graph shows the "learned increasing trend" since these values are forecasted values with the model.predict(X_forecastdays)